# How to open an excel without running the Workbooks.Open macro in it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a  vba code that calls my procedure whenever openning that excel.

```
Sub WorkBook_Open()
Call Sheets("Result").main
End Sub
```

My concern is , that main function will send email out. So in future if I want to edit that excel, how can i open it without triggering the call?

My initial intention was to use command line to run the vba function everyday and send that report automatically

Comment: If the invocation needs to be conditional, why not *make it* conditional? `If MsgBox("Send email?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then...`

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks Mat - if you don't mind me asking how to display the full content of your message..

Comment: Well the ellipsis stands for the code you're currently running unconditionally: `Sheets("Result").main` ('call' is redundant/useless/obsolete)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open the Excel Application.
2. Go to File ~ Open, or File ~ Recent.
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while opening your file.

**NB:**  This won't work by just selecting the Excel workbook to open.
You need to open Excel first and then open the workbook.

**Edit:**

> My concern is , that main function will send email out.

Don't add your code to the `Workbook_Open` event, add it to the click event of a button instead - it'll never send out emails until you press the button then.

Comment: Thank you. Button wont be an option because i want to run the macro from command line

Comment: Hmm then a msgbox isn't ideal at all. I'd research to see if there's a way to specify conditional compilation arguments from command-line (possibly not). Basically Excel automation without a UI isn't a recommended scenario. Good luck!

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks, yeah i agree. Initially used powershell to generate the excel report but there are lots of reformatting to do based on values which needs to be done with html while composing the email body(not attachment). so I turned to VBA instead.

Comment: No longer works as of December 2023.  (There are no versions of Excel any more, just Windows Update...)

Comment: @Tuntable it works if you select Browse to open the file, but not if you're selecting the Pinned workbooks on the Open screen. Bit of a pain, but whoever said Microsoft wanted to make things easy (well, apart from Bill Gates).

Answer (score 2):

I've found the following works for me in Office 365 (maybe other versions of Excel too) -

1. Open Excel directly, do not double-click a workbook to start Excel
2. File/Open/Browse
3. Navigate to the workbook you want to open, single click on it
4. Click the dropdown next to Open, and Open in Protected View

If you want to edit further at that point, you'll have to click Enable Editing on the popup that should appear just under your menu bar.  When I do that, I have macros that try to run right away, but they fail, and I can edit the VBA.  YMMV there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since some certain version, holding shift no longer works. I added the following to reinstate the functioning:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnKey Key:="{+}", Procedure:="StopMacro" '+ is the shift key https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey

Call MakeRec

End Sub

Sub StopMacro()

' do nothing.

End Sub

Comment: In which version and build number does holding down Shift no longer work? Note that the call to `Application.OnKey` does not stop `MakeRec` from being called, it just tries (and fails) to assign the `StopMacro` Sub to presses of the Shift key.

Comment: I have found that the Shift key has stopped working in "some verison of Excel"  (There are no versions any more, just Windows Update.  Ugg!)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to open Excel first.  Simply hold down the shift key while double-clicking the .xlsm file.